# Azure web app random 502 errors. No crash no slow requests

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

This week we have started getting 502 errors on our Web App, these are random; some times they happen when there is consistent load other times they happen with even a single request.

I have checked event viewer and there is no application crash, also don't have any really slow requests in IIS logs. I had auto-heal enabled, which is now disabled. I have also enabled auto scale and even with 4 instances running I get 502 error every once in a while. There is no log entry for this 502 in IIS logs, so I am guessing something upstream is returning this response, I just don't know why its doing that and why its so random.

Comment: Dup of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/902b1979-52e9-4955-bd97-d8037c836de5/random-502-errors?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Try enable Failed Request Tracing.

Comment: Its already enabled, and I haven't seen anything that would explain the 502 responses. The only one I see is a failed fav icon request.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, we get randomly 502s and logs does not reveal anything. Event in the application insight there is nothing about these errors. But other failed errors like 404 are logged in Application insight

Comment: In my case I was able to get past the issue by scaling up to dual core VM, in my testing I noticed that I started getting 502's anytime responses from my app where going beyond 500 ms (just a theory I have no means of proving it). This got us moving for now, at later point we are going to do some more performance testing to find out what really happened.